# Where to write data which should persit until next application startup?

Tags: linux, fhs

To be compliant with the FHS I'm going to install my application in `usr/local` and the corresponding subdirectories. Where should the application write data which persits until the next application startup?

Comment: probably in `/var/usr/local` as it is variable data

Comment: or ~/.app/ if the data is per user

Comment: What type of application is this? What is the state that needs to be saved? Is it dependent on the user that runs the application?

Comment: @R3turnz you probably mean `/usr/local` (with a leading slash; not `usr/local`), no?